# Replace middle of filepath while keeping filename at the end?

Tags: bash, sed, perl

I am trying to manipulate a file path using bash. The first part of my goal has been completed, where I replace the first half of the file path with the path on my local computer.

```
$> fp=$"/projects/bison/git/bison_20190405/assessment/LWR/validation/HBEP/analysis/BK363/HBEP_BK363_out.csv"
$> echo $fp | 
    sed -E "s#/projects/bison/git/bison_[0-9]{8}#/Users/djm/Documents/projects/bison#"

$> /Users/djm/Documents/projects/bison/assessment/LWR/validation/HBEP/analysis/BK363/HBEP_BK363_out.csv
```

The next part I am having trouble with. I would like to replace everything between `/analysis/` and the file name with `/doc/figures/FILENAME`, including analysis. I have been able to create this functionality using an Rscript but can't figure out how I would keep the filename in the pipe statement.

**Expected Input:**

```
/Users/djm/Documents/projects/bison/assessment/LWR/validation/HBEP/analysis/BK363/HBEP_BK363_out.csv
```

**Expected Output:**

```
/Users/djm/Documents/projects/bison/assessment/LWR/validation/HBEP/doc/figures/HBEP_BK363_out.csv
```

Here is my current Rscript with the necessary regexp:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

test <- "/projects/bison/git/bison_20190405/assessment/LWR/validation/HBEP/analysis/BK363/HBEP_BK363_out.csv"

str_replace_all(test, "/projects/bison/git/bison_[0-9]{8}",
                      "Users/djm/Documents/projects/bison") %>% 
  str_replace_all("(?:analysis).*$", 
                  paste0("doc/figures/", basename(.)))

#> [1] "Users/djm/Documents/projects/bison/assessment/LWR/validation/HBEP/doc/figures/HBEP_BK363_out.csv"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use sed again

```
 sed 's#/analysis/.\+/#/doc/figures/#'
```

For your input:

```
$ echo /Users/djm/Documents/projects/bison/assessment/LWR/validation/HBEP/analysis/BK363/HBEP_BK363_out.csv | \
sed 's#/analysis/.\+/#/doc/figures/#'

/Users/djm/Documents/projects/bison/assessment/LWR/validation/HBEP/doc/figures/HBEP_BK363_out.csv
```

Comment: hmmm it's not working for me. I'm on macOS if that makes a difference. I've seen that sed can act differently depending.

Comment: @dylanjm does it work if you replace `\+` with `*` ?

Comment: that worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: @dylanjm Alright, it seems that `\+` is GNU specific. `*` should work fine, but keep in mind that `\+` means "one or more characters" while `*` means "zero or more", so this would trip up on something like `/analysis//BK363/HBEP_BK363_out.csv`(notice the doubleslash which will still be a valid filename in bash, but will cause sed to not replace the `BK363` after.)